# Create document with python

Tags: python, ms-word

Is there a library that create a word document with a specific size (width - hight)?

What I want to do is to create a word document that takes photo, date, name as input and put them in a specific positions in the document.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll have to have some details in your question.  Otherwise, the answer is "Yes".

Comment: You're going to have to specify what type of document and exactly what you mean by 'size' to get assistance with this question.

Comment: Your question is not very clear : what sort of document and what's about the size ?

Comment: I thinks there might be duplicates in terms if you mean `generate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035183/how-can-i-create-a-word-document-using-python

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking you can use OpenOffice uno (SDK) for generating documents and then save them to word format (If by size your mean A4/A2... format then it work in OOo too). I haven't done this in python I used uno from java and c# but I think it should be even easier in python.

Here the link for Python-UNO bridge http://udk.openoffice.org/python/python-bridge.html

But it kind of hard to understand what your asking for, so please be more specific and update your question :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Darius Kucinskas :) , I updated my question to be more understandable.