# Saving files openoffice Python

Tags: python, save, openoffice-writer

I'm working on a script to create an OpenOffice document. After this i want to save the file. Maybe later also as an PDF.. Google doesn't give me any information how to fix this..

My question here is: What method should be used to save an openoffice-writer document?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your precise technical question isn't clear or is too general. Please fix it.

Comment: What do you have so far? In what format?

Answer (score 1):

You should look at this similar question which answer covers both MSWord and OOWriter (by the way, creating a Word file could be the easiest to be read with OpenOffice).

[How can I create a Word document using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035183/how-can-i-create-a-word-document-using-python)

Alexis

Comment: I'm also using a win32com. Is it possible to achieve this with win32com?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a rtf file with pyrtf or it's variants, and for pdf you can use reportlab. These are libraries for use in python, not to control remotely oo. There are other libraries for other formats.