# take lines from a .txt file and copy to a word .doc

Tags: python, text, if-statement, ms-word

I want to take lines of text from a .txt file and copy it to the bottom of an existing word doc. i have something that does this from one text file to another but the overall goal is to copy it to the bottom of a word document for a report.

I am using python 2.6 and currently have

```
with open('Error.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for line in open('2_axis_histogram.txt'):
        if line.startswith('Error'):
            f1.write(line)
        else:
            f1.write("No Error ")
    f1.close()
```

I have no idea about how i could then transfer this to word.

Also, when there is no error and the else condition is used, it prints out the "No Error" loads of times whereas i just need it to print that statement once.

Comment: Have you checked Google? Google lead me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035183/how-can-i-create-a-word-document-using-python which, while a slightly different question, it offers the answer to yours.

Comment: 'write' only happens once it prints it out multiple times because it's happening for each line.  Also, you're closing your file mid-stream...and you don't need to close when you use 'with'

Comment: Note, use 4 spaces for tabs when writing python.

Answer (score 1):

first question : use Google, or StackOverflow search : [Reading/Writing MS Word files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/188444/reading-writing-ms-word-files-in-python)

second question : get your ´No Error´ display out of the loop...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx

This is a module that creates, reads and writes Microsoft Office Word 2007 docx files.

Comment: i have tried intsalling the module but no joy it says cant fine the docx module but i can see it any ideas>

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the extraneous `"No Error"` messages, put the `else` statement into the `for` loop, not the `if` because the latter is checked on every line:

```
with open('Error.txt', 'w') as f1:
    for line in open('2_axis_histogram.txt'):
        if line.startswith('Error'):
            f1.write(line)
            break            # Exit the for loop, bypassing the else statement
    else:                    # Only executed if the for loop finishes
        f1.write("No Error ")
```

Also, no need to close `f1` - the `with` statement already is taking care of that for you.

Comment: @martineau: There are already answers that handle the other part - I don't like redundancy much. Well, that's what I get for answering a double question :)