# Can I use Word documents in XML format as a template?

Tags: xml, pdf, ms-word

Original idea: use a PDF template to create multiple pages after reading a CSV file

I've found that PDF isn't as friendly as I thought
(Especially when I want to code using PHP)

What I want: a pre-formated document with place holders for a few fields of data
The look and design of the template document are really important - so I don't want to consider using code libraries and constructing the PDF document from scratch

Now... I've had a lightning bolt of an idea: use a Word format document that is in XML format. If in XML format, surely I just can't go wrong?? If its XML, I can use any scripting language?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Good idea for using MS-Word template and then exporting it to pdf.
Rather than xml format, you can go about it like this:

- Create a word template with text,heading,tables etc. and bookmark each with unique name eg. paragraph 1 is bookmarked as 'para1'
- Create a new .net C# project & include Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (Google for more)
- Now in your C# project access those text fields in word file using bookmark names & populate it with Data from database. ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd264733.aspx)) It's as simple as:

  ```
  Document wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(@"C:\test.docx");
  Bookmark bkm = wordDoc.Bookmarks["para1"];
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng = bkm.Range;
  rng.Text = "It was never a tough job to automate....";
  ```
- Save & close the document([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63w57f4b.aspx)) or you can export/print it to pdf (Google it)

Comment: Sounds awesome. Thanks for the reply. I was thinking of using Python. This would allow me to develop web versions + a stand alone that I could turn into an executable and run on Windows and Mac. (I know I can make standalone on Windows, not sure about Mac).

Comment: Also... I don't want to be reliant on .net, so would want to discount for that reason. I'll look into creating bookmarks though. I'm sure that will help.

If I have chosen XML format to be the default format of my documents, then do I still have to create a XML file from Word? Doesn't actually make a difference though - happy to have an XML.

Comment: Ya no worry you can use xml format and automating with C# was easy for me but you can search for python word automation & see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035183/how-can-i-create-a-word-document-using-python