# display:table is not working after converting to word

Tags: html, asp.net, wcag2.0

I am using DIV for layout my .aspx page in order to be WCAG 2.0 Compliant as below:

```
<div style="display: table;">
<div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell;">Hello</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;">World</div>
</div>
```

This is working properly in all the browser but when I am converting it to Word instead of being displayed in horizontal it will be displayed in vertical format.

How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/28714894/3597276

Comment: Thanks for your comment but in that link it's using Table element which will work fine during conversion but I am using display:table.

Comment: Not sure how that makes a difference. The only reason the HTML `<table>` element behaves like a table is because its [default style (from the user agent stylesheet) is `display: table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).